# Drupal console set site:mode

Tags: console

I installed a site use composer with command

```
composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev some-dir --stability dev --no-interaction
```

I would like to set site mode to dev. If site install drupal from drupal.org, I can run command

```
drupal smo dev
```

But with composer I run

```
vender/bin/drupal list
```

and don't saw any command about setting site mode. How can do that with Drupal site install by composer. I would like to run command line, **don't want config file service.yml**.

**Note: I ready run composer update.**

Answer (score 1):

The correct command for setting site in development mode is

```
drupal site:mode dev
```

Check here for more details - [Debugging compiled Twig templates](https://www.drupal.org/node/1903374)

Answer (score 1):

drupal site:mode dev is disabled in current version (RC 17) of [Drupal Console](https://github.com/hechoendrupal/drupal-console).

See here: https://github.com/hechoendrupal/drupal-console/issues/3079

and in code: https://github.com/hechoendrupal/drupal-console/blob/master/config/services/drupal-console/site.yml

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this issue. The error message I got was:

```
[ERROR] Command "site:mode", is not a valid command name.
```

My Drupal Console version was 1.8.0.

I had to specify the URI parameter to get it to work like this as I did not have a default site:

```
drupal --uri="example.org" site:mode dev
```